# What is the 'cleanest' way to roast eggplants indoor?

Tags: roasting, eggplant

Whenever I've tried to roast eggplants on the oven, it takes more time to clean than to cook. Any suggestions?

Comment: You *are* poking the skin before you bake them, right? Otherwise you'll have lots of clean up (and little eggplant left intact).

Answer (score 4):

What is taking so long to clean, your sheet pan? Put a sheet of parchment paper underneath the eggplant.

Comment: That's the only thing I could think of... I roast eggplants all the time and have never found it to be cleanup-intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible alternative. Maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but I find one of the best ways to prepare eggplant is to slice into about 1cm or 1/2in thick slices, optionally do the salt-and-wait-to-get-the-liquid-out-then-pat-dry song and dance routine, then lightly oil them and cook on my searing hot cast iron stovetop griddle.

Answer (score 1):

From the nickname "kocakafa" I see that you are Turkish. So am I and I use a pan you can buy easily in any utensil selling store in Turkey for eggplant roasting. I am attaching the image. It is very easy to use and the cooking time is significantly reduced as the cleaning time.

[image: eggplant grilling pan1]

[image: eggplant grilling pan2]

Comment: For those of us who aren't Turkish ... is there a name for the pan, if we wanted to try to find one?  (it looks to be a heavily glazed pan, similar in depth to a pie pan,  but with a flared outer lip and some sort of groves or ridges on the inside)

Comment: I doubt that you can find it easily outside of Turkey. But if you could ask a middle astern market in your area, they might be able to help. It is called "(eggplant) roasting pan" or "grilling pan" "közleme tavası" in Turkish, nothing too fancy :) It is actually a very thin and light pan with glazing. very cheap. there are slits inside for the heat/flame to penetrate.